# apache2 page doens't read php

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on my digitalocean droplet. Everything seems to work fine but on my web page the php gets commented out.

[image]

```html
<!--?php
include 'modules/start.php';
include 'templates/header.php';

//page switch
switch ($page){
    default:
    include 'templates/landing.php';
}
?-->
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.
** Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.**

Comment: If you uncomment ?

Comment: That is the render display or the code you wrote? What does `<?php echo 'hello world';` output?

Comment: Your php is not being executed. Make certain you have one of these : `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in your httpd.conf, then reload apache, php-fpm

Comment: I've figured it out. I haven't had a PHP module installed on my ubuntu....... Thanks!